# Content-Security-Policy errors

Tags: javascript, html, css

After reading multiple sites nothing has worked thus far to allow me to use this bootstrap template: https://github.com/StartBootstrap/startbootstrap-freelancer

I even added the meta tags but the errors got worse, what am i doing wrong?

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="style-src 'self' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css 'unsafe-inline';"
/>
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'self' use.fontawesome.com 'unsafe-inline';"
/>
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'self' code.jquery.com 'unsafe-inline';"
/>
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net 'unsafe-inline';"
/>
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'self' https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js 'unsafe-inline';"
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to use crossorigin="anonymous" with your script src or link i think that can resolve the problem

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Reglages_des_attributs_CORS

Comment: I did and it did nothing, same old errors. I even moved all the css and js into separate files and still nothing...

Comment: you can try to download the libraries locally and use them